# Using differentials to estimate the volume of a cylinder.

Tags: calculus

Given a cylindrical storage tank that is $14$ meters tall, use differentials to show how accurate as a percentage the diameter must be calculated in order to calculate the tank's volume within $4$% of its true value.

Answer: I am given that the acceptable error in measuring the diameter is $2$%.

I tried the following:

$\frac{|\text{actual} - \text{estimate}|}{\text{actual}} \times 100 \leq 4$

For my "actual" I used $V = \frac{1}{4}d^2 \pi h$. Here, I made the substitution $r = \frac{d}{2}$ because I'm interested in the diameter.

For my "estimate" I used $dV = \frac{1}{2}d \pi h (dd)$, where $(dd)$ is a differential.

When I work out the algebra, I am not seeing where I might get to $2$%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that the relative error of any variable $x$ is $$\delta x = \frac{dx}{x}$$

and the percentage error is just that quantity multiplied by $100$. So from the problem it's given that the percentage error of $V$ is 4%, or

$$\delta V = \frac{dV}{V} = .04 $$

and it's asking you to find, the percentage error for $D$, or $\delta D = \frac{dD}{D}$

We have

$$ V(D) = \frac{1}{4}\pi D^2 h$$

where $h$ is a constant.

Differentiate to get

$$ dV = \frac{1}{2} \pi hD \, dD $$

Divide both sides by $D$

$$ \frac{dV}{V} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} \pi hD \, dD}{\frac{1}{4}\pi D^2 h} $$
$$ \frac{dV}{V} = 2 \frac{dD}{D} $$
$$ \delta V = 2 \delta D $$

Therefore $$ \delta D = \frac{1}{2} \delta V = .02 = 2\% $$

You can see that this is true for any $h$. If $V$ is equal to a constant times $D^2$, no matter what the constant is, then $\delta V = 2 \delta D$.

The same holds for any power: if $y = kx^n$ then $\delta y = n \delta x$. This relation is pretty neat because it saves you from doing all of that algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Let us write, just as you did $$V = \frac{1}{4} D^2 \pi h$$ and let us look at the sensitivity of $V$ with respect to $D$; as you did, this requires to go throught derivative.

The first way is to do as you did and the write $$dV=\frac{1}{2} D~ \pi~ h~ dD$$ and now divide by $V$ the left side and by its expression the right side. So, $$\frac{dV}{V}=\frac{\frac{1}{2} D~ \pi~ h~ dD}{\frac{1}{4} D^2 \pi h}=2 \frac{dD}{D}$$ Going from $dV$ and $dD$ to $\Delta V$ and  $\Delta D$, we have $$\frac{\Delta V}{V}=2 \frac{\Delta D}{D}$$

A fatser way to get the same relation would have obtained using logarithmic differentiation.

In any manner, I am sure that you can take from here and get the result.